# Change maven settings.xml location and pass -s automatically

Tags: bash, maven, cmder

### Intro

I moved my settings.xml file to a secured network share which only I can access.
The next step is to encrypt various credentials inside the file as well.

Unfortunately, now when I run mvn I need to specify the location every time, e.g.:

```
mvn -s Z:\CONFIG\settings.xml
```

### Solution Try - Aliases

I tried making an alis in CMDER but I always get a `goal not specfied error`.

E.g. in user_aliases.cmd I add the following tries:

```
mvn1=echo "Using custom cmder alias (cmder user_aliases.cmd) :  mvn -s Z:\CONFIG\settings.xml " & mvn -s Z:\CONFIG\settings.xml

mvn2=mvn -s Z:\CONFIG\settings.xml
```

They both fail with an error about goals not being passed.

So this is an issue with the arguements not being passed.

---

**Anyone  have a solution for hardcoding this location permanently???**

### Update

My current solution has been to edit the mvn.cmd file itself.

I added something like the following, and it works.....
though it breaks mvn for anyone else wanting to use it:

```
echo "Modified mvn.cmd to add custom path mvn -s Z:\CONFIG\settings.xml " 

"%JAVACMD%" ^
  %JVM_CONFIG_MAVEN_PROPS% ^
  %MAVEN_OPTS% ^
  %MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS% ^
  -classpath %CLASSWORLDS_JAR% ^
  "-Dclassworlds.conf=%MAVEN_HOME%\bin\m2.conf" ^
  "-Dmaven.home=%MAVEN_HOME%" ^
  "-Dlibrary.jansi.path=%MAVEN_HOME%\lib\jansi-native" ^
  "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=%MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR%" ^
  %CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER% -s Z:\CONFIG\settings.xml  %MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS%
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error
goto end
```

I could possibly make a copy of maven to my Z drive (secured) and call that to avoid all of this.

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve by putting the `settings.xml` in a non-standard place?

Comment: @ J Fabian Meier  It's a shared virtual PC that I am currently using, but that other people have access to. SO first off, I don't want my credentials copied (which can be solved by using encryption), and secondly - I don't want the settings file itself to be copied in general. Using a secure network share takes care of both (sort of... will encrypt). I guess I could use my own version of maven from a secure shared folder

Comment: Other people have access to your user directory?

Comment: @ J Fabian Meier Yes, because everyone has admin previleges on the specific machine.

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea to build on that machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried two solutions which both worked:

### Move maven to folder with permissions

One solution was to move maven directly to a protected isolated folder such a shared network folder (with appropriate permissions) or user folder.

## Edit the mvn cmd file

I edited the mvn.cmd file itself.

I added something like the following, and it works.....

**WARNING: it breaks mvn for anyone else wanting to use it. So use only if this is not a consideration**.

```
echo "Modified mvn.cmd to add custom path mvn -s Z:\CONFIG\settings.xml " 

"%JAVACMD%" ^
  %JVM_CONFIG_MAVEN_PROPS% ^
  %MAVEN_OPTS% ^
  %MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS% ^
  -classpath %CLASSWORLDS_JAR% ^
  "-Dclassworlds.conf=%MAVEN_HOME%\bin\m2.conf" ^
  "-Dmaven.home=%MAVEN_HOME%" ^
  "-Dlibrary.jansi.path=%MAVEN_HOME%\lib\jansi-native" ^
  "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=%MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR%" ^
  %CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER% -s Z:\CONFIG\settings.xml  %MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS%
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error
goto end
```